# App.Config Vs Web.Config

Tags: vb.net

Basically I'm needing to do this in app.config:

```
<system.web>
       <identity impersonate="true" userName="Username" password="Password"/>
</system.web>
```

How do I accomplish this? Currently been researching this with no luck? any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: `identity` is part of `web.config`. What exactly you want to acheive

Comment: I'm building a console app and I'm getting access denied when I call the exe. I did the exact same thing in a web app and use the impersonate code above not getting the error

Answer (score 1):

USe `NetworkCredential` class:

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(
    SecurelyStoredUserName,SecurelyStoredPassword,SecurelyStoredDomain);
```

It will allow you to enter websites, access remote shared folders , etc...

By the way, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can impersonate from the app.config - What you might need to do is launch a process in your code that impersonates another user. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347870/system-diagnostics-process-impersonating-other-user) related post.

Answer (score 0):

You can not impersonate another user like that in a desktop application. Look into impersonation. One question that might help you is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net). [This entry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) on CodeProject implements a C# class that helps you impersonate another user.